# How to configure or customize Docker Registry to authorize access at the tag level

Tags: docker-registry

I'm using the Docker Registry published at https://hub.docker.com/_/registry and I've written my own authorization server to implement our custom access controls, but there is a snag:  The scope information passed to the authorization server does not include the tag part of the pull command.

We would like to enforce authorization at that level in addition to the repository.

Does anyone know if it is possible to do this?

Do I need to fork the Docker Registry project?  Would that even work?
Is there an existing fork that already does this?
Is there an undocumented configuration option I've missed somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nope, not possible. Tags are meant to convey discrete versions of the same basic software. If you need to permission versions differently, they need their own repos.

Comment: In some license models at some organizations, users only get access to certain versions and updates depending on their license purchases.  I was also hoping to use the version/tag to pre-stage new versions and make them available with the flip of a switch rather than make them available immediately on push.  Amazon's registry product allows access control by tag, but they are the clear outlier in that regards.